# Gov system: How to fix com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)

Tags: python, outlook, cac

I am trying to programmatically cycle through my emails using python using win32com.client.

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)

for idx, folder in enumerate(mapi.Folders("email@mail.com").Folders):
    print(idx+1, folder)

messages = mapi.Folders("email@mail.com").Folders("Inbox").Items

print([message.Body for message in list(messages)[:10]])
```

When I do this I get the error `com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)` When I try to access the messages.Subject, everything works fine.

I am operating on the gov (cac enabled) computer and my guess it has something to do with certificates or with permissions. Can anyone confirm this? Thank you!!!

Comment: Does this happen on the very first message? Or only on a particular one? Try to print the Subject property first, then Body - this way you'll know which item causes the error.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: happens on the first .Body item. The .Subjects all print out with no problem.

Comment: What kind of message store is it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to answer that question. What do you mean? I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: Is it PST? Exchange? IMAP4?

Comment: I believe it’s an exchange.

Comment: Okay yes almost certainly an exchange. It’s dod email.